# software to deploy fast markdown to HTML static pages?

Tags: html, markdown, static-site-generator

I want an web application that I can deploy markdown notes and serve it into HTML static pages quickly. Minimal css and very minimal formatting.

Is there a web application that does this?

The idea stems from having "notes in the cloud". There's already an app similar to this called notepad.pw, but the issue is that i can't embed images on there. Neither can I do this with github gists, etc.

Naming of URL links can be completely random, like `http://notepad.pw/amw6v81j`, `imgur.com/XXXXX`, or gify, or something like `https://gfycat.com/detail/QuaintPersonalDoctorfish`.

Is there an application similarly to these with the option of embedding images?

The only things I can think of is something like JSfiddle or something like that

This would solve a couple of problems

1. When I talk to people on livechat handling technical issues, I can just send a link of notes without linking it to reddit, a blog site, or anything else or just massively sending imgur links to them
2. I can make on-demand notes to a client describing how to do some simple task if I can't find any good resources for it (E.G. some app specific to some industry)
3. Nontechnical client can bookmark those notes on google chrome. Those notes would be specific to them, say how to login to their website, do specific task in specific software they use, etc
4. You can add a login to those notes and password protect it. Optionally you could use these pages as a training manual to say if you hire freelancers, VA's, that kind of thing.
5. A communication tool. You can send a link of notes instead of an email with contents
6. Design documents. It would be similar to a PDF with the ability to add gifs inside of it (hosted by imgur) since its HTML
7. Easily shareable to anyone with password.

How it would compare to other programs out there:

- Its basically github gist 2.0 or pastebin 2.0 with images, mixed in with a online markdown to html previewer, and notepad.pw or gyfcat URL naming conventions with a history log of sites made to manage all the static pages with a password login
- It'd be kind of like gitbooks.io but for just a single page, private login, and password protection to serve mostly only mostly HTML, minimal CSS, and images
- Or it'd be like an online markdown to HTML like stackedit.io but publicly viewable in a specified URL path with read-only permissions
- Or a password protected JSfiddle.com focused only mostly on markdown to html notes

I have a feeling this already exists I just don't know what its called. You could use website to do all of this (wordpress, quora, blogger), but I want a bunch of words, images, gifs into its own randomly generated URL deployed in 30 seconds or less that's not associated with any blog platform

**tl;dr**

I want a quick and dirty markdown to HTML site builder that makes its own randomly generated URL path with password protection but isn't associated with anything like reddit, quora, blogger, zendesk, github, etc that can be made in 30 seconds or less.

I feel like this might exist already but Idk what its called.

It should be freeware (not licenced) or pay-monthly service. I run Windows, it should be a backend framework not client side. I found something similar to what I was looking for called roughdraft.io through Github which works but I wish I could have some privacy controls / password controls on there.

Comment: Should run in what environment (e.g. PHP, Python frameworks or stand-alone native Linux/Windows)? Any license concerns (e.g. must permit commercial use)? Any price range / budget limit?

Comment: it should be freeware (not liscenced) or pay-monthly service, I run windows, it should be a backend framework not client side, I found something similar to what I was looking for called roughdraft.io through github which works but I wish I could have some privacy controls / password controls on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the python world there are several well known static web site generators to take a look at but I would suggest taking a look at:

- [Nikola](https://getnikola.com/)
- [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/) or
- [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) *if you prefer Ruby*

All allow static web site generation, and local hosting, from markdown including showing images & referencing external links.

Any of the above will generate your static web site for you - you then need to upload it to a location that it can be connected to possibly with the privacy protection enabled - this is more a service than anything else, *and hosting sites with things like privacy and high availability will almost always be charged for*, but some options to look at, *(all charged I am afraid)*:

- [GitHub for Business](https://github.com/business)
- [Box Business Plans](https://www.box.com/en-gb/pricing)
- Amazon [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) + AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)

Comment: thanks for the information here. I think all of these solutions are overkill for what I'm looking for and I'll resort to roughdraft.io and gists